# The adapter doesn't show the current element?

Tags: java, android, json, get

The adapter shows only one item will JSON has more than that number how can the adapter shows all the JSON elements? i have loader and it is only shows one element and repeat it?
the JSON ger elements doesn't show in the adapter I tried things but it doesn't work !! how can I show and take every single element from the response.

the image shows the elements

[image: the image shows the elements]

the adapter:

```
  public class shelfsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < shelfs > {
      public shelfsAdapter(MainActivity context, ArrayList < shelfs > objects) {
          super(context, 0, objects);
      }@
      Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View listItem = convertView;
          if (listItem == null) {
              listItem = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                  .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
          }
          shelfs current = getItem(position);
          TextView title = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
          title.setText(current.getTitle());
          TextView author = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.author);
          author.setText(current.getAuthors());
          return listItem;
      }
  }
```

the loader:

```
    public class LoaderApp extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<shelfs>> {
      private String url;


      public LoaderApp( Context context,String mUrl) {
        super(context);
        url = mUrl;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onStartLoading() {
        Log.v("forceload","force close dossseeeeeee!!!");
        forceLoad();
      }

      @Override
      public  List<shelfs> loadInBackground(){
        if(url==null){return  null;}
        Log.v("get books","get books");
        List<shelfs> books = QueryUtils.fetchData(url);
        Log.v("get query","get query");
        Log.v("equals query","equals"+books.get(0)+""+books.get(2));
        //  books.add(new shelfs("books","books inback "));
        return books;
      }
```

the main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<shelfs>> {
  private   shelfsAdapter adapter;
  private static final String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q={search%20terms}";
  private static final int ID=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     //final String url1="  https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=1\n";
         adapter = new shelfsAdapter(this, new ArrayList<shelfs>());
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Log.v("geturl fine","fine get it");
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Get details on the currently active default data network
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // If there is a network connection, fetch data
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
            android.app.LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
            Log.v("loading ","loader inflater");
            // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
            // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
            // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(ID, null, this);
        }}




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<List<shelfs>> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        Log.v("get load","get load on create");
        Toast.makeText(this,"creat it just!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adapter.add(new shelfs("oncreat","loadApp on create loader"));

        return new LoaderApp(this,url);


    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<List<shelfs>> loader, List<shelfs> data) {
    if(data != null && !data.isEmpty() )
        Log.v("get load","get load on finished");
       // adapter.add(new shelfs("onloadfinish","addall??"));
        adapter.addAll(data);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Log.v("data add","data"+data.get(0)+""+data.get(6));
       // Toast.makeText(this,"data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<List<shelfs>> loader) {
        Log.v("get load","get load on reset");
        adapter.clear();

    }
```

and the json class:

```
public class QueryUtils {
    public QueryUtils(){}

    public static List<shelfs> fetchData(String requestUrl)  {
        if (requestUrl ==null) {return null;}
        Log.v("fetchData work!","fetchData work!");
            URL uRl=getUrl(requestUrl);
        Log.v("geturl work!","geturl work!");
        String json=null;
        try {
             json=makeHttprequest(uRl);
            Log.v("makehttp work!","makehttp work!");
        }catch (IOException e){Log.v("error fetch","error fetch");}
        List<shelfs> makeit=ExtractJsonData(json);
        Log.v("extractdata work!","extractdata work!");
        return makeit;
    }

    public static URL getUrl(String urlhttp) {
        URL url=null;
        try{ url=new URL(urlhttp);}
        catch (MalformedURLException e){Log.v("url error","url error",e);}
        return url;
    }


    public static String readStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        if(inputStream!=null)
        { InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line=reader.readLine();
        while(line!=null){stringBuilder.append(line);
        line=reader.readLine();}}
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static String makeHttprequest(URL url)throws IOException{
        String jsonResponse="";
        InputStream inputStream=null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
        try {
            urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConnection.connect();
            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200)
            {inputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse=readStream(inputStream);
                Log.e("connect error","connect");}}
            catch(IOException e){Log.e("connect error","connect error");}
            finally{
                if(urlConnection!=null){urlConnection.disconnect();}
                if(inputStream!=null){inputStream.close();}
            }
            return jsonResponse; }


    public static List<shelfs> ExtractJsonData(String jsonResponse){
        List<shelfs> putshelfs=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject base=new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray items=base.getJSONArray("items");
            shelfs firstShelfs=new shelfs("","");
            for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject index = items.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject volume=index.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                String title=volume.getString("title");
                JSONArray authors=volume.getJSONArray("authors");
                String auth=authors.getString(0);
                 firstShelfs= new shelfs(title,auth);
                putshelfs.add(i,firstShelfs);

                Log.v("gggg","net get"+i+auth+title+"dom");}
            Log.v("dff","json take");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }

        return  putshelfs;}

}
```